# Python Integer for loop 200 to 205

Tags: python, arrays, list, python-2.7, set

I need to input a list of http-response codes into my application config and want to provide a python shorthand so they won't list off each single code.

something like the following:

```
class settings: 
  success_codes= 200..299        # successful request
  retry_codes= 400..404,500-503  # retry later
  fail_codes = 504,505,506       # don't retry again
```

doesn't python support some kind of clean syntax like this to define ranges? I need multiple ranges.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `ranges`, in Python 2.x:

```
success_codes = range(200, 300)
retry_code    = range(400, 405) + range(500, 504)
fail_codes    = range(504, 507)
```

And for reference, in Python 3.x (also works in Python 2.x):

```
success_codes = list(range(200, 300))
retry_code    = list(range(400, 405)) + list(range(500, 504))
fail_codes    = list(range(504, 507))
```

Answer (score 1):

just use the range function:

```
vals = range(start, stop + 1)
```

Comment: `vals = range(start, stop + 1)`, no?

Comment: yeah, I just always remember that its doing that and adjust accordingly. Will update answer though for clarity.

Answer (score 1):

This works across all versions of python

```
class settings: 
  success_codes = list(range(200, 299 + 1)) # successful request
  retry_codes = list(range(400, 404 + 1)) + list(range(500, 503 + 1)) # retry later
  fail_codes = list(range(504, 506 + 1)) # don't retry again
```

In earlier versions of python, `list(range())` can be replaced by `range()`. Also, obviously, you can add the 1 to the upper value directly.

Answer (score 1):

Using range(n, m+1), like a lot of people are suggesting, works. However, do you need to create all the possible values in memory?

In most cases you can use:

```
if return_code < 200 or return_code >= 299:
    do_something()
```

Or:

```
if return_code in range(200, 299+1):
    do_something()
```

Comment: yes this is how it'll be used, but based on the program configuration I want them to have complete control on when the program should repeat/retry the request and when not to. I'd rather not hard-code it.

Comment: Depending on how much programming capability you are expecting from the people going to configure the thing, you could also store a callable to the settings and execute those as part of the comparison.

Comment: I'd prefer no logic in the settings, just values. But that's just me. most of the people will be engineers.

Comment: I can see that. However, `range()` is logic as well. That is a smell that you may be making it too configurable.

Comment: hmmmm. you're right. I can just take the config value and pass it to range(). but since most of the engineers know ruby and python, i wanted to see the exact syntax where the it's being plugged into. if I just say syntax is [X,Y]+(A,Z)+[U,T,S], it'll look weird.

Comment: Oh, just a thought. You could use lists (or tuples) to mark ranges: `success = [[200, 297], 299]`.